# ToolBar becomes so much bigger on 19+ API in android

Tags: android, toolbar

I want transparent `StatusBar` as well as `NavigationBar` in my app. thus I've achieve this using:
**values/style.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
```

**values-v19/style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

[image: Activity on Lollipop]

But, when it runs on `Lollipop` or `Kitkat` device, The `ToolBar` Appears so much bigger then the normal size. How to avoid this?
Here's the `ToolBar` code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tbHomeToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I've change some property of `ToolBar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tbHomeToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

But, it becomes even worse[image]

**EDIT**
I gave the partial answer of my question. It might help to understand more about what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm giving the answer of my own question because I don't find solution what I exactly want.
**Solution 1:**
By just removing the

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

from `values-v19/styles.xml` it's works perfactly.
but, that's not what I want.
**Solution 2:**
it's also possible using `FrameLayout` and using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` with `FrameLayout` not with `ToolBar`.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.sparrow.chargeup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sparrow.chargeup.HomeActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tbHomeToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:navigationContentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

but, It gives fully transparent `StatusBar` like this[image]
but, I want something like this with transparent navigation
[image]
 I will go with `Solution 2` if I can't found the exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `?attr/actionBarSize` for `minHeight` attribute use it for `layout_height` attribute refer the below code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tbHomeToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"   
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: it works but, now it looks like [this](http://s12.postimg.org/yj9ov2tfh/Screenshot_2015_04_24_17_45_42.png)

Comment: Then you can give the height like this for diferent resolutions
1:values    
    -dimens.xml    
        <dimen name="toolbar_height">35dp</dimen>

2:values-xlarge
-dimens.xml   

        <dimen name="toolbar_height">50dp</dimen>

Comment: If you wanna keep the same height for all the resolution just increase the height

Comment: See my answer, It might help you to understand what I want.